# Always getting negative Y front view (on gizmo) by default when pressing 1 on the NumPad

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera, axis, gizmo

**Preface:** the course I'm watching now is covers Blender 2.8, but I going through it using the latest 3.3

**Course side:**

I'm watching the [Blender Launch Pad](https://www.cgboost.com/courses/blender-launch-pad) course. I've noticed that when the author switches to the front view, using the [1] on the NumPad, gizmo in the top-right corner of viewport is always shows non-negative axis. Regardless of the side. So, no matter does he pressed just [1] or [CTRL + 1] or [2] or [CTRL + 2] etc. it always appears as non-negative in the video:

*User Interface Fundamentals - Viewpoints tutorial - 01:32*

[image: COURSE_SIDE_GIZMO]

**My side:**

On the my side if I press for example [3] or [7] it by default shows me first the non-negative side of view, `X` and `Z` respectively (it's alright). When I press [CTRL + 3] or [CTRL + 7] it shows the negative ones. But in the course this is not happens (it always appears non-negative).

Also the annoying thing is that when I press [1] to switch to the front view it always switches me to the negative side by default firstly:

[image: MY_SIDE_GIZMO]

Then I should press [CTRL + 1] to switch to non-negative `Y` side.

Generally I have the two questions:

1. Is that what happens on my side with the front view a bug of blender?
2. Why on the authors side, in the video, it always non-negative regardless of actual side of view? Maybe I can do the same in preferences, somehow? Or does that confuse is caused by blender version difference?

Comment: Sorry for being boring with such a stupid questions but I'm new in blender and that questions is pretty important for me now

Comment: it's normal to see -Y if you press 1, as -Y is pointing towards us, I don't know why it's not the case in the tutorial, maybe a developer mistake for this version?

Comment: @moonboots oh, I've just now downloaded the old `2.80rc2` version from the blender website and noticed that there minus just didn't appears at all in gizmo. The negative sides was denoted as a circle with a small border. It's not such a obvious and very hard to discover in the tutorial. It looks the minus for that purpose just appeared since the `3.0` version. And in the video it starts with the negative `Y` by pressing [1] too. Thanks for your commentary.

Comment: oh ok it explains

Comment: Axel, you might post this as a self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded the old `2.80rc2` version from the [blender website](https://download.blender.org/release/) and discovered that there minus didn't appears at all for denote negative side in gizmo.

The negative sides was denoted as a circle with a small border. It's not such an obvious and hard to discover in the tutorial. It looks the minus for that purpose appeared only since the `3.0` version. And in the video it starts with the negative Y too by pressing <kbd>1</kbd>.

Also now, thanks for @moonboots commentary I know that it is normal to see `-Y` when press <kbd>1</kbd>.